# Image fires onload event, but image is still undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a fiddle located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlowgren/dpDXp/) illustrating my problem, namely that when I load images using the `Image` object, `onload` gets called but the returned object is still `undefined`.

Here's the code in case the fiddle were to disappear into the void:

```
var ImageManager = function() {
    var _images = [], 
        _loaded = 0;

    var precache = function(imageArray) {
        if (!(imageArray instanceof Array)) {
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
            if (typeof imageArray[i] !== 'string') {
                continue;
            }

            _images[i] = new Image();
            _images[i].onload = function() { 
                _loaded++;
                document.write('<p>Successfully loaded: ' + imageArray[i] + ' [' + _loaded + '/' + imageArray.length + ']</p>'); 
            }
            _images[i].onerror = function() {
                document.write('<p>Unable to load: ' + imageArray[i] + '</p>'); 
            }
            _images[i].src = imageArray[i];
        }
    };

    var get = function(imagePath) {
        if (!_images.hasOwnProperty(imagePath)) {
            document.writeln('<p>' + imagePath + ' isn\'t precached!</p>');
            return null;
        }

        return _images[imagePath];
    };    

return { get: get, precache: precache }
};

// Test case starts here:

var testImages = [
    'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png',
    'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png',
    'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'
];

var imageManager = new ImageManager();
imageManager.precache(testImages);
```

Sample output:

> Successfully loaded: undefined [1/3]
>
> Successfully loaded: undefined [2/3]
>
> Successfully loaded: undefined [3/3]

As per usual, it's likely something obvious I'm overlooking. Aid me, ye all-knowing oracles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` inside the event handlers are always equal to `imageArray.length - 1`, because `i` increases during the loop. Wrap the loop's body in a closure:

Also, don't use `document.write`, even for debugging purposes. Use `console.log(..)`, `alert(..)` or at least `document.body.innerHTML += ..`.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dpDXp/7/

```
for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    if (typeof imageArray[i] !== 'string') {
        continue;
    }
    (function(i){ //<-- This

        _images[i] = new Image();
        _images[i].onload = function() { 
            _loaded++;
            console.log('Successfully loaded: ' + imageArray[i] + ' [' + _loaded + '/' + imageArray.length + ']'); 
        }
        _images[i].onerror = function() {
            console.log('Unable to load: ' + imageArray[i]); 
        }
        _images[i].src = imageArray[i];
    })(i); //<-- This
}
```

Comment: Might be less confusing to name the argument-`i` otherwise than `i`.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I don't normally use `document.writeln`, but did so now to illustrate the output on jsFiddle without resorting to the console.

Comment: For clarification, `i` at the end is the `i` as declared at the `for(var i ... )` block, `i` inside the closure is a *different*, *local* `i` as declared as a formal parameter at `(function(i) {`.